# Currency locale for devexpress pivot field

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, locale, pivot

Is there a way to set a field`s locale by designer in a devexpress pivot?
Or i should do it by some way with code?

What i want is to have a field to show euro currency whatever locale user have in his machine.

Comment: which platform? Win, ASP, WPF, SL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read an article [here](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q255672.aspx)

Comment: A reference is great, but please make sure your answer is self-contained. Posting only a link isn't really an answer most of the times.

Comment: Of cource, but for DX - they have support, when you can ask anything. Also, without working sample it's difficult to create new version. and yes, comment is better than an answer, I;ll try to comment first (: